# What do you use (free) to format C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format

Are there any VS.NET plugins that will format a selection of code for printing or emailing and is also free?

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked the inbuilt formatting provided by VS? Select code and enter key chord Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F.

Or goto (menu)Edit->Advanced->FormatSelection or Edit->Advanced->FormatDocument

Answer (score 3):

If you copy your code from Visual Studio and paste it into Word, the syntax highlighting will be kept.

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [Copy Source As HTML](http://www.jtleigh.com/people/colin/software/CopySourceAsHtml/) add-in.

Comment: I didn’t know about the copy/paste to Word. That’s awesome! +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Is this just a matter of using spaces instead of tabs to do indent your code?

Answer (score 1):

try Artistic Style 1.22, http://astyle.sourceforge.net/

it's easy to use, has 3 or 4 predefined styles and is configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of tabs-to-spaces function, and make sure the print or email uses a `monospaced` (aka. typewriter or console) font.

I'm pretty sure VisualStudio had a (little well hidden) function to convert indenting from tabs to spaces and vice versa.

I'm normally using [vim](http://www.vim.org/) where you can use:

```
:set expandtab
:%retab
```

to replace tabs with spaces and:

```
:set noexpandtab
:%retab
```

to replace spaces to tabs.

Spaces is better for emailing etc. because noone can agree on the length (in spaces) of a tab.

Answer (score 0):

To turn tabs to spaces, select the code and use `Editor -> Advanced -> Untabify Selected Lines`.